# Text Outside of viewable area

Tags: android, android-layout

In my view, the text is stretching beyond the screen as seen here:

[image]

Here is the layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBasicProfileProjectName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/double_dash"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_holder"
            android:src="@drawable/nature444photo" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_basic_profile_project_status"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_projectstatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/double_dash" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_basic_profile_project_type"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_projecttype"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/double_dash" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_basic_profile_project_contact"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_projectcontact"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/double_dash" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/nature_green_header"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/label_project_relationships"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp" >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/nature_green_header"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/label_related_global_priorities"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_rel_global_priorities"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/double_dash" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp" >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/nature_green_header"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/label_related_regional_priority_strategies"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_related_regional_priority_strategies"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/double_dash" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp" >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/nature_green_header"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/label_related_whole_system_priorities"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_related_whole_system_priorities"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/double_dash" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp" >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/nature_green_header"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/label_related_demonstration_priorities"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_related_demonstration_priorities"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/double_dash" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/nature_green_header"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/label_geographic_whole_system"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_geographic_whole_system"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/double_dash" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/nature_green_header"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/label_project_description"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_project_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/double_dash" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/nature_green_header"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/label_programs"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_programs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/double_dash" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/nature_green_header"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/label_tnc_region"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_tnc_region"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/double_dash" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/nature_green_header"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/label_countries"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_countries"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/double_dash" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_basicprofile_modified"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/double_dash"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And, within Eclipse. this is what I see when I select the element.

[image]

Even here, the container shows to exceed the display.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

**Update 1: added complete layout.**

**Update 2: added snapshot of layout within Eclipse.**

Comment: please put your whole layout as some of the layout properties is also depend on which is the parent layout.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer I've added the complete layout file. Thanks.

Comment: So hope you got the right answer so there is no need to add my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you have used `wrap_content` for the width of the `TableLayout` and `TableRow`s?
This is the only thing that could cause this behaviour. I think you should use `match_parent`.

(I haven't tested your layout, but it's the only thing that looks wrong to me).

Comment: I made that change but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Ah, I've just noticed another thing: in your second `LinearLayout`, the one with the gray background and horizontal orientation, you have an `ImageView` with a width of 200dp, and a vertical `LinearLayout` with a width of `match_parent`. I'm almost sure this is the problem. The linear layout matches its parent width, and then the image view is added, which would account for the additional width. You should use a width of 0dp for the child linear layout and set it's `layout_weight` to 1

Comment: If this doesn't fix it, try using the `stretchColumns` property of the TableLayout, because there you have something similar: a `TextView` with a fixed width of 150dp in the first column and a second column containing a TextView with width set to `wrap_content`. I think you should set `stretchColumns` to stretch your second column and your second TextView should have it's width `match_parent`.